# PHPMailer Class And Gmail: The sent emails not retain in Sent directory in Gmail

Tags: php, gmail

I used PHPMailer class to send emails

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

The sent emails not retain in Sent directory in Gmail.

Where I'm wrong ?

```
    try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

    $body             = file_get_contents('ct.html');
    $body             = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Strip backslashes

        $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                                   // 1 = errors and messages
                                                   // 2 = messages only
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
        $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $mail->Username   = "*******@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
        $mail->Password   = "*******";            // GMAIL password

        if($mail->SmtpConnect()){
            echo "SmtpConnect";
        }else{
            echo "ERROR";
        }

        $mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail

        $mail->AddReplyTo("*******@gmail.com", "*****");

        $mail->From = "*******@gmail.com";
        $mail->FromName = "*******";

        $to = "receiver@*******.***";

    $mail->AddAddress($to);

    $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message " . rand();

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    $mail->Send();
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
```

How I can storing emails in Sent Directory ?

Thank in advance !

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: [Sent mails with phpmailer don't go to Sent IMAP folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561495/sent-mails-with-phpmailer-dont-go-to-sent-imap-folder), though I am not sure about the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264249/mails-sent-via-smtp-should-get-reflected-in-the-sent-folder-on-the-email-server) seems to relate to your problem and it seems that they don't get stored when using smtp. However, you could BCC the sending account and just filter those mails in a separate folder.