# Send Email From Java and See That Email in a Web Hosted Email App

Tags: java, email, smtp, webmail

**My Objective**

I want emails sent from a Java Web App to be visible in the Sent folder of my web hosted email client. This will be a 'log' of all emails sent by the Java Web App.

**Background**

I can send an email from my Thunderbird email client on my Mac from **abc@xyz.co.uk** to any email address and I can see it in my **abc@xyz.co.uk** account on **Easily JustMail** in the **Sent** folder.

**The Problem**

When I send an email from **abc@xyz.co.uk** using Java Mail with all the same settings as Thunderbird, the email does NOT appear in my **abc@xyz.co.uk** account on **Easily JustMail** in the **Sent** folder.

**Please Note**. The email itself does arrive at its **to address**, so it is NOT a problem with the actual send process.

I have even sent emails manually using telnet but they don't show in Easily JustMail either...

**Settings**

Email Account / From Address = abc@xyz.co.uk

host = smtp.easily.co.uk

port = 1025

Authentication required: true

User Name = uSeRnAmE

Password = ******

So, it would appear that desk-top email clients are doing something slightly different to Java Mail or telnet...

Any ideas?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264249/mails-sent-via-smtp-should-get-reflected-in-the-sent-folder-on-the-email-server

Comment: Thanks Bob Brinks but both Thunderbird and my Java apps are using SMTP to send the email. Obviously, Thunderbird does something else behind the scene to get the email stored in the 'Sent' folder. My question is, what is done and how can that be done in Java Mail...